# Have + verb-ing participle

Tags: grammaticality, difference

I'm wondering if the following sentences have the same meaning. Does the second one sound natural in English?

> I can't sit there because her bag is standing there
>
> I can't sit there because she has her bag standing there

I'm also curious if i need to put the word "has" in the second example into present continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct.

> I can't sit there because her bag is standing there.

In this case, "her bag" is the *subject* of the 2nd clause. "Her bag" is the main topic of the clause.

> I can't sit there because she has her bag standing there.

In this example, "she" is the *subject* and "her bag" is the *object*. "She" is the main topic of the clause.

Both sound natural to me. I think the 1st sentence sounds a little better but there's little difference in meaning.

Comment: Thanks! But i would like to ask something else: do i need to put "has" in present continuous? Or simple present is ok?

Comment: The meanings are subtly different. The first emphasizes the bag and its presence. The second emphasizes the woman's role in having _placed_ the bag in that location. The second also suggests the woman herself is present with the bag.

Comment: There is a subtle difference which I kind of pointed out but it's small enough to be ignored by beginners.

Comment: @So_sour About your extra question, please edit your post and include an example.